# How to convert date using dateformatter for "YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm[:ss[.uuuuuu]][+HH:MM|-HH:MM|Z]"?

Tags: ios, swift, date, nsdateformatter, dateformatter

The date I get from the server is in this format `"2020-11-28T19:24:58.478641+05:30"`
but I can't convert it to a date using date formatter.

```
  let input = "2020-11-28T19:24:58.478641+05:30"
  let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
    formatter.dateStyle = .full
    formatter.setLocalizedDateFormatFromTemplate("YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm[:ss[.uuuuuu]][+HH:MM|-HH:MM|Z]")
    formatter.timeStyle = .full
    
    let date = formatter.date(from: input)
    print(date)
```

The `print(date)` returns nil in every case. I tried converting this online which was successful in https://nsdateformatter.com/

[IMG ->converted date on nsdateformatter.com](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9GzYT.png)

How to fit the server date to an iOS existing date formats?

Comment: in which formate output needed?

Comment: Stop using the `timeStyle` and `dateStyle` if you use a date format, else, you're breaking the output. Want a little tip? What's expecting as a string your formatter: `print(formatter.string(date: Date())`, you'll see. Also `YYYY`, `DD` etc, it's case sensitive, I don't think you want them uppercase. And it's not a regex, it's no `[+HH:MM|-HH:MM|Z]`, it's not the hour here, it's the timezone.

Comment: `formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSZZZZZ"` should the the trick then.

Comment: yes changing into this format did the trick, thanks a lot @Larme!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the [ISO8601DateFormatter](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/iso8601dateformatter)?

```
let formatter = ISO8601DateFormatter()
formatter.formatOptions = [.withInternetDateTime, .withFractionalSeconds]
let date = formatter.date(from: input)
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
let dateString = "2020-11-28T19:24:58.478641+05:30"
let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSz"
let date = formatter.date(from: dateString)
date // Nov 28, 2020 at 5:24 AM
```

Comment: You can add a single S for fraction seconds is enough to parse up to 3 fraction digits. DateFormatter will always discard any fraction digit after the third one. Note also if OP uses the same format to generate a string from the resulting date it in GMT+/-x instead of +XX:XX. depending on the device's current timezone. So it would be better to set the date formatter's timezone to UTC and change its dateFormat to  `"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXXXX"`

Comment: Thanks, I did not know these points @LeoDabus

Comment: @LeoDabus that was really helpful, I guess I was not able to find the suitable format until now.

Comment: @rebel_codeaz you can’t use dateFormat and dateStyle together. Remove your last 3 lines of code above  date(from: input)

Comment: ya, got it. Also to convert into my local time, I also need to specify the timezone as TimeZone(abbreviation: "GMT")